# UITextView is partially scrolled down when view opened

Tags: ios, objective-c

I create a `UITextView` and add a lot of text to it. When I launch the view, the `UITextView` is always partially scrolled down. Of cause the user can scroll up, but it just feels weird.

What happens? Did I miss any obvious settings?

Please refer to the following image. Part of text is cut out. I borrow the text from [link](http://www.cisco.com/public/sw-license-agreement.html).

[image]

I started a simple Single View Application. This is how my `viewDidLoad` looks like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"license"
                                                     ofType:@"txt"];
    NSString* terms = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                                encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                   error:nil];
    self.textField.text = terms;
}
```

And this is my storyboard:

[image]

This is how it looks after manually scroll up to the top.

[image]

Comment: Can you scroll up to the point that if you don't touch the textview you still see the first line of text? I ask this because the textview might be behind the navbar...

Comment: @NicolasS Yes, I can scroll back up with no problem.

Comment: Hi @NicolasS, I just added another screenshot. Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this line at the end of your `viewDidLoad`:

```
[self.textField scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
```

Like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"license"
                                                     ofType:@"txt"];
    NSString* terms = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                                encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                   error:nil];
    self.textField.text = terms;
    [self.textField scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
}
```

Comment: thanks for the tip, but there are still few pixels missing on the top of text (padding)

Answer (score 3):

This used to happens on all iPhone/iPod devices under landscape mode, and solutions by the others will work. Now it only happens for iPhone 6+ or iPhone 6s+ under landscape mode. This is a work around for it:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.textView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
    });
}
```

The view is scrolled somehow after the `viewWillAppear` and before `viewDidAppear`, and that's why we need the dispatch above.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I solved it by getting the previous scroll position and reseting it after updating the "text"

```
CGPoint p = [self.texField contentOffset];
self.textField.text = terms;
[self.textField setContentOffset:p animated:NO];
[self.textField scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange([tv.text length], 0)];
```

Comment: Setting the contentOffset to CGPointZero worked for me, but only when I dispatched it into an async call on the main thread. If I called it in viewDidLoad directly, I found it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

For those using Xamarin, this is the only solution that works for me:

```
textView.Text = "very long text";

DispatchQueue.MainQueue.DispatchAsync(() =>
{
    textView.ContentOffset = new CGPoint(0, 0);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

The best working solution for me (Objective C):

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
     [self.myTextView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];
}
```